# What is ".items" and ".json()"

Tags: javascript, angular

I am reading ng-book about Angular 2, there is a piece of code:

```
return this.http.get(queryUrl)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
      // console.log("raw item", item); // uncomment if you want to debug
      return new SearchResult({
        id: item.id.videoId,
        title: item.snippet.title,
        description: item.snippet.description,
        thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
      }); 
    });
  });
```

What is `.json()` in line 3? I have googled around, but cannot find any description for this method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Http` object you are using returns an `Observable<Response>` object whenever you call any request, in this case, a `get`.

The [`Response` class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html) has method called `.json()` which attempts to return the body of the `Response` object as a parsed `JSON` object in order to make it easier to work with it.

The `items` is just assuming that the response body has an items property, so the `get` he's doing is expecting something like this to be returned:

`{ items: ... }`

Take a look at:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html

and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html